# cannot use operator= with std::stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stringstream

I am trying to make a `struct`, in which one of the members is of `std::stringstream` type. I am using C++11, and according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/operator=/ I can do it.

Here is my code:

```
struct logline_t
    {
        stringstream logString; /*!< String line to be saved to a file (and printed to cout). */
        ElogLevel logLevel; /*!< The \ref ElogLevel of this line. */
        timeval currentTime; /*!< time stamp of current log line */

        logline_t& operator =(const logline_t& a)
        {
            logString = a.logString;
            logLevel = a.logLevel;
            currentTime = a.currentTime;

            return *this;
        }
    };
```

It doesn't compile, as I am getting this error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>& std::basic_stringstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I have tried `logString = move(a.logString);` as well. Same result. I would appreciate all help.

Edit: Here is my code, I have applied the changes suggested by most of the users and in my code they do not compile. I am still getting an error at the very beginning of the `struct`.

[CLogger.h](https://pastebin.com/dmjwHwJR)

Line 40: `../src/CLogger.h:40:9: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’`

[CLogger.cpp](https://pastebin.com/U1viYEEx)

Line 86: `../src/CLogger.cpp:86:41: error: use of deleted function ‘CLogger::logline_t::logline_t(const CLogger::logline_t&)’`

Line 91: `../src/CLogger.cpp:91:9: error: use of deleted function ‘CLogger::logline_t::logline_t(const CLogger::logline_t&)’`

If any other information is needed i will provide it.

Comment: The link you posted contains all information needed: `copy (1) 
stringstream& operator= (const stringstream&) = delete;`

Comment: How to solve this problem? `operator<<` doesnt work as well. @ildjarn i am using an arm crosscompiller `gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1)`

Comment: `stringstream` is not copyable. If you actually do need to copy it, I guess you'll need to write an assignment operator that reads the contents of the stream and writes it to a new one.

Comment: @JonathanPotter but I tried `logString << a.logString;` and it gives the same error.

Comment: streams are never copyable, and are also not movable with libstdc++ prior to 5.1.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło, according t o all your comments below you are also getting a **different** error from the one in your question, which means you have a **different** problem. Stop complaining that answers to your question don't fix some other problem that you haven't shown. You are obviously trying to copy construct the type in addition to the code you have shown in your question Fix your question to show the real code.

Comment: I can post all my code, but that will only shadow the problem even more. I have updated my question with some additional info.

Comment: Please don't post links to external sites. They'll go down eventually, rendering this question useless for furture readers. Ensure all relevant code is posted in the question body.

Answer (score 12):

`std::stringstream` is not copyable. To copy the content you can just write the content of one stream to another:

```
logString << a.logString.str();
```

**Update**: 
Also if you don't follow a good advice to implement `operator=` with copy-and-swap idiom using copy constructor, you have to clear the stream first:

```
logString.str({});
logString << a.logString.str();
```

or just

```
logString.str(a.logString.str());
```

Also you may be tempted to use `rdbuf()` instead:

```
logString << a.logString.rdbuf();
```

but this is incorrect, because it alters the state of `a.logString` (despite that `a.logString` is `const`, `a.logString.rdbuf()` is a pointer to non-const object). This is demonstrated by the following code:

```
logline_t l1;
l1.logString << "hello";
logline_t l2, l3;
l2 = l1;
l1.logString << "world";
l3 = l1;
// incorrectly outputs: l2: hello, l3: world
// correct output is: l2: hello, l3: helloworld
std::cout << "l2: " << l2.logString.str() << ", l3: " << l3.logString.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło note `.str()`

Comment: I dont understand, could you clarify?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło here's a [demo which compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64898e8417b6e9d3)

Comment: @AntonSavin you are using c++14, I have c++11. Might it be the case I cannot compile?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło : The code shown _here_ is C++03 ([corrected demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c3c7a54b958a0e5)).

Comment: @AntonSavin I dont get it then, It doesnt compile for me. I am getting an error: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_iostream<char>::basic_iostream(const std::basic_iostream<char>&)’`

Comment: It would be a good idea to clear the `logString` before adding to it.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło that's a **different error** that is coming from a different piece of code. Noone can help with that part because you haven't shown the other bit of code. Fix your question.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło so you don't have copy constructor, nor move constructor, and they are deleted by default. Provide them as you've been advised in other answers, and everything will work.

Comment: You mean more Galik or more Cheers solution? Because i am very confused right now, i had no idea that this question will have so much good feedback.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Actually it looks like you can just remove `operator=` altogether, in that case your struct will have an implicit move constructor and move assignment operator, which seems sufficient.

Comment: But how could i ise '=' with 3 different objects in the struct.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło you can. The compiler generates it for you.

Comment: You are right, it worked out but for there solution where the `logString` member is a `string` not `stringstream`. In the solution I am trying to aquire i am still getting an error with `use of deleted function`

Answer (score 4):

Streams are not copyable. But they are movable.

Still you could make your copy assignment operator work by just creating a suitable `stringstream`.

On the third hand it doesn't quite feel right to have a stream as a member? And if you really want that, why not use an `ostringstream`, why a `stringstream`? By reflecting on this, the design might be improved (and possibly that will the remove the current problem).

---

Example of workaround by creating a suitable `stringstream` (well, `ostringstream`), using the exception safe copy/swap idiom:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>          // std::swap

namespace my {
    using std::ostringstream;
    using std::swap;

    struct S
    {
        ostringstream line;

        void swap_with( S& other ) noexcept
        {
            swap( line, other.line );
        }

        auto operator=( S const& other )
            -> S&
        {
            S temp( other );
            swap_with( temp );
            return *this;
        }

        S() = default;

        S( S const& other )
            : line( other.line.str() )
        {}
    };
}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    my::S o1, o2;
    o1 = o2;
}
```

Note that this relies on `std::swap`, which is specialized for `ostringstream`.

---

Example of a simpler but in principle not exception safe workaround:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>          // std::swap

namespace my {
    using std::ostringstream;
    using std::swap;

    struct S
    {
        ostringstream line;

        auto operator=( S const& other )
            -> S&
        {
            line.str( other.line.str() );   // This can in theory throw, but.
            return *this;
        }

        S() = default;

        S( S const& other )
            : line( other.line.str() )
        {}
    };
}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    my::S o1, o2;
    o1 = o2;
}
```

Comment: I tried with ostringstream, its the same error. I need any usable stream, just not `std::string` because i will need to create a local `ostringstream` and then copy it to that `string`

Comment: `ostringstream` doesnt have any method allowing you to check either it has any content or not and I need this in my application.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: You can very easily check whether an `ostringstream` has content or not, in various ways, and the code above shows half of one way to do it. I suggest that you ask a new question about this, because it's unrelated to the original question. There's generally good documentation at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: I see, thank you for answer. If the current aproach fails to i will try this asap.

Answer (score 3):

### Reason:

`std::stringstream::operator=` acquires the contents of its right hand side, by move-assigning its members and base classes.

In your overloaded `operator=` the input argument is `const`. Thus, the input argument's member `logString` cannot be moved. Additionally,  the `operator=(std::stringstream const&)` in `stringstream` is declared deleted. Overload resolution chooses a deleted operator and rightfully you're getting a compile error.

### Solution:

```
logline_t& operator =(const logline_t& a) {
  logString.str(a.logString.str());;
  logLevel = a.logLevel;
  currentTime = a.currentTime;
  return *this;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc8a3b0a69665ccf)

Comment: I am getting error at this line all the time `struct logline_t` with `error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’` it seems like it doesnt compile only because `stringstream` is a member.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło have your tried the solution above?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło I posted a Live demo please take a look at it. It works fine.

Comment: It doesnt compile for me, I am getting the same error all the time.

Comment: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’` at struct definition

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło This can't be because in my solution there's no assignment of one stringstream to another. There must be something else going wrong.

Comment: well at one point i am doing `logline_t retVal = move(*m_data.front());` where `deque<logline_t*> m_data;` but this should work as it is kind of another scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to copy a [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) object which is *non copyable*. You can get round this by not copying the object itself but copy its contents into the new [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Also you really need a *copy constructor* as well as the *copy assignment operator*. The need to provide both of these (and usually a destructor as well) is explained in the so-called [Rule Of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29#Rule_of_Three).

Also we need to add a *default consructor* because adding a *copy constructor* prevented the compiler from generating its own *default constructor*.

```
struct logline_t
{
    std::stringstream logString; /*!< String line to be saved to a file (and printed to cout). */
    ElogLevel logLevel; /*!< The \ref ElogLevel of this line. */
    timeval currentTime; /*!< time stamp of current log line */

    // default constructor needed because we made a copy constructor
    // which deleted the compiler generated default constructor!
    logline_t()
    : logLevel(0) // set suitable defaults
    {
        gettimeofday(&currentTime, 0); // for example
    }

    // copy constructor
    logline_t(const logline_t& ll)
    : logString(ll.logString.str()) // construct from contents .str()
    , logLevel(ll.logLevel)
    , currentTime(ll.currentTime)
    {
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    logline_t& operator=(const logline_t& a)
    {
        logString.str(a.logString.str()); // assign from contents
        logLevel = a.logLevel;
        currentTime = a.currentTime;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: With this update I dont get the error I had before, but instead I cannot declare the struct and assignt it anymore: This `logline_t logline;` generates `error: no matching function for call to ‘CLogger::logline_t::logline_t()’`

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło sorry i forgot a default constructor! will fis it now

Comment: Your example is the only one that compiles for me. The problem is that The streams are empty after i fill them. Damn this is a horror, I think the best way is just to use `string` as the member :(

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Okay I made an alternative *copy assignment operator* see of that works?

Comment: same effect, empty stream :/.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło That's odd, my tests show that `std::stringstream` should work that way, it may be something else you're doing?

Comment: I will post more code today, as I cant continue to test this for now, although i really want to get it working eventually.